# No sound trying to play a Python sound on Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, pygame

Just wondering if anyone can help me get the sound to work on a Raspberry Pi?

I keep getting an error message:

```
Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav') AttributeError: module 'pygame.mixer' has no attribute 'Sound'
```

Is there something wrong in the code or my setup? My code is below!

Thanks

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav')

Sound.play()
```

**the error I'm getting is:**

```
File "/home/pi/gpio-music-box/cowbell.py", line 11, in <module>
Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav')
pygame.error: Unable to open file '/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav'
```

Here is also a video of the issue I'm having!
[My Python code error](https://youtu.be/aJwTc5l5X2A)

Comment: You have two errors in your question, but you can only be getting one of those. Which one are you getting? To answer the second error: you need to initialize `pygame.mixer`. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845896/pygame-cannot-open-sound-file

Comment: Moreover, this question is general programming question - not specific to the Raspberry Pi. You may have better luck asking on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Your error (and the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html)) says it all: `pygame.mixer` has no attribute `my_Sound`.

It does, however, have an attribute named `Sound`, which you have in your posted code. However, you error line shows you using `my_Sound` instead of `Sound`.

Moreover, your `pygame.init` should be a function call, that means it needs `()`. So it should be:

`pygame.init()`

All in all, you code should be:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

Sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('/home/pi/gpio-music-box/samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav')

Sound.play()
```

Comment: my code is what you have put! just my mistake not changing the error code in the text above! I will do that now do you can see I'm still getting the error even with the correct things you mentioned e.g () I already add at one point its with me keep making changes to see why it will not work, See above again I will change it to what is is now with errors. Thanks

Comment: @Dave you have just added a completely new error to your question. Please make new posts for different questions.